# GridView and objectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, objectdatasource, data-retrieval

I have a grid view that bounded to an object data source that select data from type of student

```
public class student
{
   int id;
   string name;
   int age;

   public List<students> GetAllStudents()
   {
       // Here I'm retrieving a list of student from Database
   }
}
```

In the UI Control ascx

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" 
              DataSourceID="MyDataSource" 
              OnRowCommand="MyGrid_RowCommand">
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" 
    TypeName="student"
    SelectMethod="GetAllStudents">
```

In the UI Control code behind

```
protected void MyGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     // Here I want to get the list of students from my gridview
}
```

I want to retrieve the list of data that shown in the Grid to be able to check on the age value of last student in the list

please help me as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have define OnRowCommand on my grid view and in this event , ((GridView)sender).DataSourceObject.GetView("DefaultView") , but I didn't find any thing that can retrieve my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it

I can access MyDataSource.Select() method directly and I will get a list of my objects

```
protected void MyGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     List<student> lst =(List<student>)MyDataSource.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define methods for CRUD and bind them to ObjectDataSource.

Please check this article, it is very neat and easy to understand.

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/139_GridView_With_ObjectDataSource.aspx

Comment: I have no problem with this , I have created this method and define the SelectMethod of my object data source and it is working correctly , the problem that I want to get the list of student back in some other function to do some processing